# Call SharePoint Rest from mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, rest, sharepoint, mobile

Deer all,

I am facing the issue that how to call SharePoint REST in our mobile team(Android and IOS).

The main problem is how to reach the login action.

My sharepoint environment is Windows Authentication and now I tried something as below.

Code 1, using NetworkCredentials, it works but I think it not suitable for mobile devices.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ap.2013.trial.nintex.com/_api/web?$select=title");
        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        NetworkCredential myCredential = new NetworkCredential("Justin.Liu1", "3QF0\"gn", "EXT");
        request.Credentials = myCredential;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Code 2 using CSOM which I think is also not for mobile devices.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://ap.2013.trial.nintex.com/");
        ctx.Credentials = myCredential;
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        ctx.Load(web);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        string title = web.Title;
```

Code 3 using WebService but I kept facing the 401 error.

```
//add web reference
        ctest.Authentication auth = new ctest.Authentication();
        ctest.LoginResult result = auth.Login("EXT\\Justin.Liu1", "3QF0\"gn");

        //or using webrequest
        //Site URL: https://ap.2013.trial.nintex.com
        //Username: EXT\Justin.Liu1
        //Password: 3QF0"gn
        var soapEnv = string.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                  <soap:Body>
                    <Login xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">
                      <username>{0}</username>
                      <password>{1}</password>
                    </Login>
                  </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>","EXT\\Justin.Liu1","3QF0\"gn");
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapEnv);
        HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ap.2013.trial.nintex.com/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx");
        loginRequest.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/Login";
        loginRequest.Method = "POST";
        loginRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        loginRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream requestStream = loginRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        WebResponse loginResponse = loginRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream loginStream = loginResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader lsr = new StreamReader(loginStream);
        string loginContent = lsr.ReadToEnd();
        requestStream.Close();
```

Anyone who has experiences on mobile devices will do great favour to me, thank you taking your time.

Justin

Comment: Any one give a hand?

Comment: Any one give a hand?